# submenu not showing when having get request params

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have an `navigation.xml` file, where I have a simple menu, with a submenu within the `<pages>` tag.
The submenu is working well, except when I have addition `$_GET` params which are in the url.

Like this: `admin/manage/pages/id/1`     <-- With this url the submenu is not showing

Link explained:
`{module}/{controller}/{action}/{key}/{value}`

I think I have no more information, because my setup is just basic, and the behavior strange.

Hopefully you have an idea where this is going wrong.

Bytheway: I use the default routes.

---

Edit: I use the following code for displaying the submenu's `$this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0);` (both code suggestions from **ArtWorkAD** did not work)

Here's my navigation.xml:`

    
        
            Website
            /

```
    <beheer>
        <label>Beheer</label>
        <module>admin</module>
        <controller>beheer</controller>
        <uri>/admin/beheer</uri>

        <pages>
    <paginabeheer>
        <label>Pagina beheer</label>
        <module>admin</module>
        <controller>paginabeheer</controller>
        <action>index</action>
                **//THE CODE BELOW IS ADDED ON ArtWorkAD's SUGGESTION**
                <pages>
                    <paginabeheer>
                        <label>Pagina beheer</label>
                        <module>admin</module>
                        <controller>paginabeheer</controller>
                        <action>index</action>
                    </paginabeheer>
                </pages>
                **// END ADDED CODE**
            </paginabeheer>
    </pages>

    </beheer>
</nav>
```

`

Comment: could you add your navigation.xml file? I think you got error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people say this is a bug but I think there is a simple workaround.

Have a look at this issue :[Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu::renderSubMenu() should use minDepth=1 per default](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6673)

So try using minDepth like this

```
// Navigation 1. Level
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null, 
          array('minDepth' => 0, 'maxDepth' => 0));

// Navigation 2. Level
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null, 
          array('minDepth' => 1, 'maxDepth' => 2, 'onlyActiveBranch' => true));
```

If this does not work try to add a submenu item to your submenu to see what happens, it should render you submenu now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Both solutions you provide did not work. I shall try to add my navigation.xlm.

Answer (score 0):

ArtWorkAD you were right! I have found what I did wrong.

Now the working code is: `<?= $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('navigation-submenu')->renderMenu(null,
          array('minDepth' => 2, 'maxDepth' => 2)); ?>`

So your answer was correct!
In my XML file it is needed that I have the extra sub-subpage. Thank you very much for your workaround!

I mark your post as answer.